# How can i know for any font it's allowed to use in @font-face or not?

Tags: css, xhtml, licensing, font-face, typography

How can i know for any font it's allowed to use in @font-face or not?

even if i recieve font from client, font installed in company PC, font comes with Adobe Software and MS Office?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to go and find the corresponding license. I guess you don't want to use any font you've got, so just pick some that you take into consideration and check their specific license.

Another approach would be to use free fonts like [Liberation](https://fedorahosted.org/liberation-fonts/), [DejaVu](http://dejavu-fonts.org/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page) or the [Droid Fonts](http://www.droidfonts.com/). They are all good and completely free to use.

Microsoft developed a so called [Core fonts of the Web](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_fonts_for_the_Web)-pack. This pack includes some common fonts that many people already have installed. These are free to use and to download. So including these won't be a problem either.

As far as I know you need to have a license for other fonts. If they are given to you by a customer ask the customer about the license. Otherwise you have to take care for a license yourself.

Comment: what if font came with purchased software? like MS Office, Photoshop etc.

Comment: Do you have a name of the font you mean?

Comment: for example this http://store1.adobe.com/cfusion/store/html/index.cfm?store=OLS-US&event=displayFont&code=AVEQ10065000

Comment: @metal you would have to ask adobe whether "Embedding: Preview & Print" applies to web sites as well. It's a bit unclear from the description IMO.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to what Ham already well put:

If the font came with a MS or Adobe product, you are most likely not allowed to use the font in that way. See for example [Microsoft Typography - Font Redistribution FAQ](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/RedistributionFAQ.mspx) (I quoted this in a [different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2327299/will-i-have-copyright-problems-with-microsoft-if-i-add-microsoft-yahei-bold-font) earlier but it's a slightly different context.)

> Q. What can I do with the fonts supplied with Microsoft products?
>
> A. The fonts are governed by the same restrictions as the products they are supplied with. You are not allowed to copy, redistribute or reverse engineer the font files. For full details see the license agreement supplied with the product.

There is the option of "embedding" fonts, but I'm certain that does not apply to `font-face`

> Q. Can I embed Microsoft fonts in my documents?
>
> A. Embedding allows fonts to travel with documents. Most fonts distributed with Microsoft products allow embedding. To check a font's embedding permissions, right-click on the font file and choose 'Properties'.

Check out this question for more links to Open-source and free fonts:

- [How to use web-fonts legally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1805324/how-to-use-web-fonts-legally)